# Enums in Python: Building chess pieces

Tags: python-3.x, enums, chess

I am trying to build a simple chess board in Python 3 and I am a bit lost representing the pieces properly. I thought it would be a reasonable idea to defined values for every colour and piece like that:

```
from enum import Enum

class Piece(Enum):
    "This class represents a piece and its colour"
    Empty = 0
    King = 1
    Pawn = 2
    Knight = 4
    Bishop = 8
    Rook = 16
    Queen = 32

    White = 64
    Black = 128
```

Now I would like to represent a piece by concatenating the colour and the piece like that here:

```
squares = []
square[0] = Piece.White | Piece.Rook
```

Unfortunately, my IDE tells me that piece wouldn't have a member of type "Rook".

Is my way of using enums totally wrong? I am used to doing such stuff in other programming languages, but I am new to enums in Python. Is there any clever idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag) enum. See the documentation for example usage, but your code as written should be fine if you just change `Enum` to `Flag`.

Comment: You are right, wonderful! Thank you very much

Comment: I was getting `print(Piece.White | Piece.Rook)` with output:   `Piece.White|Rook|Bishop|King` ?  Did I not understand it?  (after changing `Enum` to `Flag`)

Comment: Well, thats another small mistake by myself. We just order the numbers of the pieces by powers of 2 such that king = 1, rook = 2, knight = 4, bishop = 8 etc. If it stays like in my question, then some pieces include each other mathematically

Comment: I will fix that in a minute in the original question

Comment: @DORpapst You can also just use `auto()` instead of assigning values manually, as described in the docs.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I haven't seen that you changed from IntFlag to Flag. Seems like Flag in combination with auto() is much better. Thank you